# Orientation of DataLabels

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I found on the internet to add the name from the legend to the point on the series in the chart. My problem has been trying to rotate the label so it is rotated 90 degrees. Would anybody know how to incorporate the orientation property into this code?

Thank you

```
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim nPts As Long

    For Each mySrs In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        With mySrs
            nPts = .Points.Count
            mySrs.Points(nPts).ApplyDataLabels _
            Type:=xlDataLabelsShowValue, _
            AutoText:=True, LegendKey:=False
            mySrs.Points(nPts).DataLabel.Text = mySrs.Name
        End With
    Next
```

Comment: In the future I recommend poking around the microsoft documentation before posting here. Sometimes it is difficult to know exactly what you are looking for but in this case you could have found your answer by googling "vba datalabel". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Point` object has a `DataLabel` member. Each `DataLabel` has a member called `orientation`. According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff822933.aspx)

> The value of this property can be set to an integer value from –90 to 90 degrees or to one of the following constants:
>
> xlDownward
>
> xlHorizontal
>
> xlUpward
>
> xlVertical

So the solution to your problem is simpy:

```
mySrs.Points(nPts).DataLabel.Orientation = 90
```

Should be simple as that :)

Comment: Thank you. And I have poked around but I have a lot to do and there are so many people who give great answers on here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked to me,

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = Sheets("MySheet").Shapes.AddChart2.Chart
Dim rng As Range
cht.SetSourceData Source:=Range("MySheet!B3:G3")
'Many other chart formatting options...

cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
Selection.Orientation = xlUpward
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.Orientation = msoTextOrientationUpward

'In my case this will put the labels in the middle of the bars
Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter

' From here it is just more formatting
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
   .Visible = msoTrue
   .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
   .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
   .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
   .Transparency = 0
   .Solid
End With
```

Comment: Generally, answers are more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.